# ssh_config: Add a host section that matches IPs even when connecting via hostname

Tags: ssh, dns, ip, openssh, hostname

I want a host section in my ssh config that matches any local IP:

```
Host 10.* 192.168.*.* 172.31.* 172.30.* 172.2?.* 172.1?.*
  setting
  setting
  ...
```

This works as long as I connect directly to a relevant IP. If I however connect to a hostname that later resolves to one of these IPs, the section is ignored.

sshd has *Match Address* sections which I think can be used for this, but they won't work in ssh client configs.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do that using only `ssh_config` options, but there is `exec` option, which can do that for you:

```
Match exec "getent hosts %h | grep -qE '^(192\.168|10\.|172\.1[6789]\.|172\.2[0-9]\.|172\.3[01]\.)'"
   setting
```

Comment: Wouldn't the `host` or `nslookup` commands be better for this?

Comment: Yes. It would work also, but this is how I know it and `ping` is more familiar for users :)

Comment: This works, thanks! Here's what I used in the end: `Match exec "getent hosts %h | grep -qE '^(192\.168|10\.|172\.1[6789]\.|172\.2[0-9]\.|172\.3[01]\.)'`