# SSH-Config - Is there a way to determine if local or remote?

Tags: ssh, ssh-config

My ssh-config currently has two entries for each host, one that has the local hostname and one that has the remote address of the host.

I'm wondering if there's a way I can combine those two entries so that ssh will automatically pick the right way to connect to the host depending on whether I'm local or remote?!

Comment: post the snippet of your configuration. There is `Match exec` switch, which can help you, but without more detail hard to say what are you trying to achieve. Something like this can help you: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260516/ssh-config-add-a-host-section-that-matches-ips-even-when-connecting-via-hostnam/260521#260521